# Excel VBA Copying from CSV to Excel Loses Original Format

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have a CSV file which I open as a Workbook in Excel VBA ( Workbooks.Open(".csv") ), I copy a certain range from the csv file which is originally text (see csv image), after pasting the range in the new excel file (see excel image), it loses its leading zeroes. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use [`Workbooks.OpenText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) instead with the correct `TextQualifier` parameter set to `xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote` to specify the format as text not number (see the documentation link). Then it should keep the zeros. Or specify in `FieldInfo` which columns are text and which are numbers.

Comment: Format the column as `000000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Workbooks.OpenText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-opentext-method-excel) instead.

You can use the `FieldInfo` to specify which column is which format (see [xlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlcolumndatatype-enumeration-excel)). To keep the zeros format this column as text.

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=mypath, DataType:=xlDelimited, _ 
    TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _ 
    Semicolon:=True, _ 
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2)), _ 
    Local:=True
```

This will format the column 1 … 4 as Text.

Comment: How do I assign this to a workbook object?

Comment: I tried this one but it still does not paste as text

Comment: Well this should work. If not, you need to show (in your question) what exactly you tried and how by giving a [mcve] (including a data sample) to reproduce your issue. Otherwise we cannot help but just give hints.

Comment: I did the OpenText method and used Array(3, 2) to format the third column of the CSV file to text, after calling OpenText, I assigned the ActiveWorkbook to a Workbook object (Set wb = ActiveWorkbook). After this, I assign the first sheet of the wb (csv) to a Worksheet object. (wb.Sheets(1)). That's when I start to copy a range from the worksheet using ws.Range("some range").Copy. And then paste it to another worksheet.. desWs.Range("some range").PasteSpecial xlValues. This still results to the missing leading zeroes same as the image shown above.

Comment: Workbooks.OpenText FileName:="file.csv", DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                           TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
                           Comma:=True, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(3, 2)), _
                           Local:=True

Comment: Is the opened CSV showing the correct numbers with zeros?

Comment: The weird this is when I open the csv file using excel, it already does not show the correct zeroes, but when I open it with a text editor, it looks like the image shown above which is the one with correct zeroes.

Comment: This is not weird but logic because Excel treats it as number and not as text. If treated as number then `004` is exactly the same value as `4` (there is mathematically no difference). Otherwise you must specify the format for the number as Patrick showed in his answer or format it as text.

Comment: I also tried using Patrick's method. I formatted both csv worksheet with "@" and the excel worksheet with "@", but still it does not show the correct zeroes after pasting..

Comment: format it as  `NumberFormat = "000000"` as he said. It's all in his answer you just need to apply it.

Comment: Yes but the problem with this is that the codes do not have a definite length.. There are some codes which are 001, some are 000101, 0100121, etc.. That's why I need the exact string of the code without any changes from the csv file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174015/discussion-between-p-and-vince-gonzales).

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your images from here, but your source is probably string of numbers.
I would apply a `NumberFormat = "@"` to the target range, and use `PasteSpecial xlValues`.

```
With targetDateRange
   .NumberFormat = "@"
   .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End with
```

Another possibility is to apply a format AFTER pasting:

```
   targetDateRange.NumberFormat = "0000000000"
```

but then you'll have numbers, not strings